# what is the mobile layer for sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, mobile, sdk

According to the MSDN documentation, "Currently, the REST service in SharePoint 2013 Preview is read-only.", so I need to identify bi-directional, r/w access to sharepoint databases and its workflow.

MSDN Doc ref: [MSDN Build mobile apps in Sharepoint 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163228%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: How do you suppose we should answer your question? What MSDN documentation? You are aware that you asking about a beta product with beta documentation? You need to identify bi-drectional access to sharepoint databases and its workflow? How does this correspond to your "mobile layer?" And what is "SharePoint's workflow" - there is no general SP workflow.

Comment: Thank you for that information.  That is a good answer toward my question.  If you want to formulate as an answer, I will be happy to award the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm... Trying my best here. What part of the MSDN documentation are you referring two. There are regular REST webservices in SharePoint 2013 which you can access almost everything of SharePoint. Right now SharePoint is in beta though, so is the documentation. Try looking for SharePoint 2013, REST and `_api` and you will find everything you need to know.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I will put that in my surfing stack.